# CMP and jmp variations in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, cmp

```
 cmp al,'0'
 je true
 cmp al,'1'
 je true
 cmp al,'2'
 je true
 cmp al,'3'
 je true
 cmp al,'4'
 je true
 cmp al,'5'
 je true
 cmp al,'6'
 je true
 cmp al,'7'
 je true
 cmp al,'8'
 je true
 cmp al,'9'
 je true
 jne error
```

I`m interested how to reduce this amount of cmp using interval and ASCII codes for numerals.
Thanks.

Comment: The ascii-codes for digits are contiguous. So you can simply check `if (x >= '0' && x <= '9')`. If you're comfortable with two's complement arithmetic, you could simplify to `if ((unsigned)x - '0' <= '9' - '0')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ASCII codes are numbers. When you write '0', the assembler transforms it to 30h = 48d. As you see in [this ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_code_chart) the letters '0' to '9' are represented by the consecutive numbers 30h..39h. So you can reverse your check: If `al` is below '0' or `al` is above '9', then goto `error`. You need only two comparisons:

```
cmp al,'0'
jb error      ; jump if below
cmp al,'9'
ja error      ; jump if above
true:
```